# Modify a view without deleting underlying table

Tags: php, mysql

I've just learned the hard way that if I delete a row from a mySQL view it removes the underlying row from the table, oops. From what I can see you can modify the view to add more entries from the original table but you can't remove one row from the view?

Basically, I create a view based on options in a form, then in the resulting list, the user has an option to remove a specific row. When they click remove, jquery posts to a script where I've got the PHP to update the view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you need to add a filter by row id to your view when user mark a row to remove, maybe use the 'NOT IN' keyword and add all rows user delete.

You are currently creating a new view for each user who filters stuff on your page, when a user removes a row all you need to do is add a new where phrase to the view definition, recreate it and give the user the new view without the removed row, clear enough?

Comment: Is there no way of finding the current criteria that built the view and then, re-submit that but with an exclusion for the row id?

Comment: What's the way? finding he current criteria?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to find the current criteria of the view and then modify as necessary. Please see question [Retrieve and alter the SQL used in a MySQL View for re-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251291/retrieve-and-alter-the-sql-used-in-a-mysql-view-for-re-execution) .

Thanks