# Retrieve and alter the SQL used in a MySQL View for re-execution

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can i get the current view criteria using php and the mysql statement "Show create view viewname"

I want to put the current criteria into a variable, amend that variable and then re-run the query. I just don't get how to use the statement from PHP.

Thanks for any help

--EDIT--

Possible code:

```
if($_POST['flag']=='flag'){
    $sqlShow = 'show create view `filter_tbl`';
    $result = mysql_query($sqlShow);
    $resultQuery = $result;
    $resultQuery .= ' AND `lead_id`!="'.$idval.'"';
    $result2 = mysql_query($resultQuery);
    echo $result;
    if($result){
        echo true;
    }
    else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please supply some example code that you're working from, or having problems wih.

Comment: Ok I've added some, I don't technically know how to perform what I need so its just a guess.

Comment: It seems to me like you just want to select something from a view with a criteria. For selects, views work as regular tables. Just do `mysql_query('select * from filter_tbl where lead_id !="'.$idval.'"')`.

Comment: Am I to understand that you're trying to retrieve the SQL that the view is using, and change *that* SQL to rerun?

Comment: @kristian ... the problem is that won't change the content of the view. I use the vie later to send emails to

Comment: Well, i'll give you an answer with what little you've provided, but not sure that I want to own it, lol

Comment: Why are you dynamically creating and altering views instead of just altering the query you perform? That makes no sense.

Comment: @kristian - I am altering the query, but I need to know what the query was, then amend, then perform a new query

Comment: He wants to use "mostly" the same SQL that the View-in-question uses, but with some additional WHERE consideration (i think)

Comment: It just seems very inefficient. Why not just store the view in the application using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get the SQL statement that the View uses:

```
$viewSQL = "SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase' AND TABLE_NAME = 'filter_tbl'";

$result = mysql_query($viewSQL);
$resultQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$SqlUsedByView = $resultQuery['VIEW_DEFINITION'];
// Now alter the WHERE clause to your needs:
$MyNewSQL = str_ireplace( "WHERE ", "WHERE `lead_id`!=".$idval." AND " , $SqlUsedByView);
```

**Note** I don't know what the actual WHERE clause of your View is, so the str_ireplace() above is just an example of how you might make your alteration.

Comment: Thats great, but how do I get the string value of the above into a variable?

Comment: Just like any other variable from a sql query, see updated answer.

Comment: Thats great thank you, I'm going to leave the WHERE as it is and just add AND != ect..

Comment: Whatever works....just understand that it's a full SQL statement, the WHERE clause may *not* be the last part of it...so there may be an ORDER BY, or GROUP BY clause, etc.